# Mysterious behavior in flex-direction: column

Tags: css, flexbox

When I write such code, I know that the text does not break.

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</div>
</div>
```

The cause of this problem is that `min-width: auto` sets the text width of the flex item to`min-width`.Therefore, this problem is solved with `min-width: 0`.

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 0; /* add this code! */
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</div>
</div>
```

Next I wrote such a code.

However, the `min-width` of that code did not work as I expected and a long word overflowed. This is a problem that did not occur at `flex-direction: row`. What is the cause of this?

**Why does min-width: 0 not work in flex-direction: column?**

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  align-items: start;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What behavior do you expect with `min-width: 0`? You're basically saying there's no **minimum** width (which means that the text can go as wide as it wants).  Also, when you describe overflowing, what do you want / expect to happen? Are you trying to control the **maximum** width? Or overflow?

Comment: I want to achieve the same behavior as specifying min-width in flex-direction: row. I added the code.

Comment: You still haven't described the desired behavior.  I think you have a misunderstanding of what min-width is intended to do, so it would be great if you would describe the desired effect.  I repeat that what you are describing sounds like you want _max width_.

Comment: Specifying `max-width`,` width` as a flex item realizes my desired behavior.

But I want to know why `min-width: 0` which works in` flex-direction: row` does not work in `flex-direction: column`.

Comment: You are missing the point: `min-width` does _nothing_ in this case.  Take it out, and the results will be identical

Answer (score 2):

For `flex-direction: row` the **main-axis** is *horizontal* and the **cross-axis** is *vertical*.
For `flex-direction: column` they switch so the **main-axis** is *vertical* and **cross-axis** is *horizontal*, you know.

Now let me remind you that
`justify-content`, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` properties work on the **main-axis**
`align-items` works on the **cross-axis**

When you set `align-items: start` you're overriding the default `align-items: stretch` and your `flex-item` can take any `width` which is greater than `min-width` (as neither `width` nor `max-width` are specified).

To achieve the desired behavior it would be enough to remove `align-items: start`;
`min-width: 0` can be also safely removed as it does nothing.

See the snippet below:

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  /* align-items: start; let's use default value instead */
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  /* min-width: 0; this does nothing */
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also in `flex-direction: row` , the `flex-item` should be able to take any width greater than `min-width` . Why do you solve by specifying `min-width: 0` ?

I do not know the reason why behavior varies depending on `flex-direction` .

Comment: @hpspera, there is a nice [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) which you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give div `.b` an explicit width, or the element will expand to fit content. Using your code, this is as simple as:

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  align-items: start;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  // min-width: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="a">
   <div class="b">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Certainly, set the same behavior as `align-items: stretch` on the flex items and solve it. But why does not `min-width: 0` work for` flex-direction: column`?